# how to set anchor tag text width using css?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have html and css as below -

```
    .title {
        display: block; background-color: red;
    }

<a href="#">
    <span class="title">Text</span>
</a>
```

I could see that the SPAN spans to the 100% of the available width (because of `display: block`). Like below

```
|----------------------------------------------------|
| Text                                               |
|----------------------------------------------------|
```

In Firefox, I can click anywhere in the above box, and it takes me to the linked page. However, In IE (IE 7) I get the cursor as hand only when I hover over "Text" text only.

What hack I'll have to do to make it work (same as it does in FF) in IE as well?

I tried placing the anchor tag itself (not just the text) in span but it won't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to make the anchor a block-element, too. Otherwise you have a block element (span with display: block) inside an inline element.

Comment: works for me (in IE6,7 and 8)...so it might be something else? If not, I'd suggest doing as David suggests below, as that is a better solution. (also works in IE6,7 and 8)

Comment: @Perix.. yes .. setting anchor as block did the trick. Cheers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Style the anchor and remove the span.

(The problem is due to how some browsers handle elements that are `display: block` inside elements that are `display: inline`. You can work around it by styling both the anchor and the span, but the span appears redundant in this example)

Answer (score 8):

for your `<a>` tag, make the style "display: block; width:100%;"

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, you need to remove the span and apply that class to the anchor tag. I don't think you need to set the width to 100% explicitly, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra span and place that title class on the link itself. Then add width:100%; to the css.

Less markup is most often better, thats why you should remove the extra span.

Answer (score 0):

you can also using margin or padding

Answer (score 0):

Give a style to anchor of `display:block` and `max-width:30px !important;` max-width size can be any

```
li a {
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    max-width: 30px !important;
}
```